# Keep webview while changing layout on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, orientation

My app have two different layout for portrait and landscape mode which both encapsulate a webview and some buttons. Buttons are at bottom in portrait and at left in landscape so more reading space is available in webview.

The problem is, the activity is recreated on screen rotation and webview loads the first page which is not a wanted behavior.

I searched and found out using android:configChanges="orientation" in activity tag prevents recreating of the activity. But the porblem is it prevents the layout changing too as it happens in activity creation.

I want my program to work in 2.2, waht's the best way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested fragments, but dealing with fragment makes things much more complex and the fragment itself needs saving and restoring which may not work in a webview which has javascript state, So I searched more and find a nice article somewhere and with some modification I came to a solution which I suggest:

First, add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden" to manifest so app handles the config change instead of android.

Make two different layout for lnadscape and portrait mode and put them in corresponding layout folders. In both layouts instead of webview place a LinerLayout which acts as a placeholder for webview.

In code define initUI method like this and put every thing related to UI initialization in this method:

```
public void initui()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if (wv == null) wv = new WebView(this);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.webviewplace)).addView(wv);
    findViewById(R.id.home).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

If the webview doesn't exist, it will be created and after setContentView(R.layout.main) it will be added to the layout. Other UI customization came afterward.

and in onConfigurationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.webviewplace)).removeAllViews();
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    initUI();
}
```

In onConfigChange First the webview is removed from old place holder and initui will be called which will add it back to the new layout.

and in oncreate call initui so the ui will be initialized for the first time.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initUI()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not save the last loaded URL in the webview in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and then make sure to reload it `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` using `myWebview.loadUrl(restoredUrl)`?

*edit* I know that this might not work if the web page you are displaying requires a state to be kept. But if not it should be a solution to your problem.

Comment: It's good idea, but on the other hand the recreation of activity seems to take some time, is there any way to just apply the new layout pragmatically without recreating everything?

Comment: If you have a different layout for landscape mode, you will have to recreate the activity. You could try to use the same layout, making it dynamic to work in both portrait and landscape. But if you need to have the buttons as described in your question I don't really see how to manage that with a single layout XML file. Have you tried to create/move/show/hide the buttons programmatically when the orientation changes? Maybe not the best solution, but if you want to speed things up it might be an option. That way you can keep the webview and just do some minor stuff with the buttons.

Comment: I tried to do it programatically, but as it's cleat that's so hard, so I searched more for a better way and I found one to do this using two XML Layout file without fragments even. It's work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

From this document https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange
I just edited manifest with android:configchanges so it works fine for me.

```
<activity android:name=".Webhtml"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```